# Filter rows from multiple sheets in Excel without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have an Excel file with three sheets, with data in each sheet organised in the same manner - headers are the same.

Without using VBA (as macros are not allowed by my organisation's security policy), I would like to find all rows from all sheets that meet a simple column value check and show those rows in a separate sheet.

For example:

Sheet2 has,
[image]

Sheet3 has,
[image]

Sheet4 has,
[image]

I want sheet1 to have all rows from sheets 2-4 with Header7 column value = "Hit",
[image]

What I have achieved so far is, using an array formula I could get all the "hits" from one sheet in sheet1.

The formula for A2 to A6 in sheet1 is as below, with the ROW(1:1) changing to ROW(2,2) and so on from A3 onwards. Columns B to G use the same formula with range adjusted accordingly.

`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet4!$A$2:$A$6,SMALL(IF(Sheet4!$G$2:$G$6="Hit",ROW(Sheet4!$A$2:$A$6)),ROW(1:1))-1,1),"")}`

What this does is a bit complicated. In short, it creates an array of either FALSE or row numbers based on Hit and then finds the index of the non-false values.

Now, I can solve the last part of combining the idea to include all sheets in two ways (I think).

1. Have another temporary sheet (sheet5) with all rows from sheets 2 to 4. Update my formula in sheet1 to use sheet5 instead of 4.
2. Have the range Sheet4!A2:A6 etc changed to include a 3D reference like Sheet2:Sheet4!A2:A6. But this doesn't work, and the documentation for 3D reference doesn't mention that it works with array functions.

PS: I don't have Power Query, which seemed to have an easy way to create a new sheet with all rows from multiple sheets, because I work on a Mac (MS Excel for Mac).

Comment: What version of excel are you on? Not having power query or the ability to use macros really eliminates the best solutions for this problem.

Comment: Yes, it does. I am using Excel 2016. But if you could use Power Query, how would you approach this problem?

Comment: Using power query, the first thing I would do is convert each of the tables into tables using `CTRL` + `T`. Then starting with the first, query that table and append the table with all the other tables. Then once they're all in one continuous table, apply the filter you wanted. Last step is to load the table to the spreadsheet. It will want to load each of the tables you queried, but you can safely delete those extra tabs, leaving only the big aggregate table. Don't delete the source tables, but if more info is added, simply refresh the power query.